# Use of consistent symbology across multiple stretched rasters in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, symbology, arcgis-pro

I have multiple rasters that represent the same thing (NDVI) at different times. Each of the rasters has a different range of values. I want to symbolise them using the same range of values (e.g. from 0 to 1) so that they can be compared. What is the best way of doing this?

[This question has been answered for ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91551/how-to-use-consistent-symbology-between-multiple-stretched-rasters-in-arcmap). However, the procedure is different for ArcGIS Pro as the options have been removed / changed.

The image below shows three of the layers with their differing value ranges:

[image: Example of differing ranges]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure on Pro is slightly different. This is how I have found is the best way to do it, however, if there is a better way, please feel free to answer.

1. Open the Symbology options for the raster layer (Right Click > Symbology)
2. Make sure the symbology is on **Stretch**
3. Choose your colour scheme
4. Change the *Stretch Type* to **Minimum Maximum**
5. Under *Statistics*, select **Custom**
6. Change the **Min** and **Max** values in the appropriate boxes that are now ungreyed below.

This does change the symbology, however it does not change the actual values. You will need to change the labels for the symbology to reflect the same values as your chosen min and max. This needs to be done for every layer individually.

The image below shows the settings used:

[image: Symbology Settings]